# Running a part of shell script as a different user

Tags: shell-script

This question has been asked before, but I can't seem to get it work.

One of the solutions I tried is using [here-document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). I used the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
su - mv2 <<EOSU
    DELIVER_BRANCH="development"
    echo ${DELIVER_BRANCH}
    exit;
EOSU
```

I tried the above code, bit `echo ${DELIVER_BRANCH}` doesn't print anything.

Comment: you can use `su - USER -c 'echo XXX'`

Comment: I think `su` does not work well when piping commands in. Maybe stdin is not used or used in some other way (could not find something in the man page). But as @Rabin said you can pass short shell scripts via the `-c` option: `su -c 'DELIVER=foo; echo $DELIVER; command1; command2 ...'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
#!/bin/bash
su - mv2 <<'EOSU'
    DELIVER_BRANCH="development"
    echo "$DELIVER_BRANCH"
    exit;
EOSU
```

Note the single quotes around the first `EOSU`.
If you omit them, the heredoc undergoes `$`-interpolation before being passed, which means that `"$DELIVER_BRANCH"` gets replaced with the current (to the shell invoking `su`) content of `$DELIVERY_BRANCH`, which is empty:

```
DELIVERY_BRANCH=production
cat <<'EOSU'
    DELIVER_BRANCH="development"
    echo "$DELIVER_BRANCH"
    exit;
EOSU
```

prints

```
DELIVER_BRANCH="development"
echo "$DELIVER_BRANCH"
exit;
```

whereas

```
DELIVERY_BRANCH=production
cat <<EOSU
    DELIVER_BRANCH="development"
    echo "$DELIVER_BRANCH"
    exit;
EOSU
```

prints

```
DELIVER_BRANCH="development"
echo production
exit;
```