# How to exit from bash script where root shell is on foreground process

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a clean up script which cleans up memory  cleanup.sh

Script :

```
# root script starts here
echo ".........running clean up script ..........."

/usr/local/packages/aime/ias/run_as_root "su -"
free -t
sync; echo 1 > sudo /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
free -t
sync; echo 2 > sudo  /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
free -t
sync; echo 3 > sudo /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
free -t
swapoff -a && swapon -a
echo "#####swapoff and swap on command ############"
free -g
exit
# root script ends here
free -g
```

script end

The script uses root and doing the stuff but could not able come out of root prompt

i tried exit 0, exit 1 and {exit} all

the process is comming to foreground , how to gabck to the shell where i started this script

running the script and script staying just as root

```
[sgongali@slc06wvd cronjob]$ ./cleanup.sh
.........running clean up script ...........
[root@slc06wvd ~]#
```

after i give exit manually what i get is below
Note that swapoff -a && swapon -a is not working as part of script but its working manually

```
[root@slc06wvd ~]# exit
logout
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      15037256   12776036    2261220     793448     382132    3357904
-/+ buffers/cache:    9036000    6001256
Swap:     15826924          0   15826924
Total:    30864180   12776036   18088144
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      15037256   12776036    2261220     793448     382140    3357896
-/+ buffers/cache:    9036000    6001256
Swap:     15826924          0   15826924
Total:    30864180   12776036   18088144
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      15037256   12776036    2261220     793448     382160    3357876
-/+ buffers/cache:    9036000    6001256
Swap:     15826924          0   15826924
Total:    30864180   12776036   18088144
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      15037256   12776104    2261152     793448     382164    3357872
-/+ buffers/cache:    9036068    6001188
Swap:     15826924          0   15826924
Total:    30864180   12776104   18088076
./cleanup.sh: line 14: swapoff: command not found
#####swapoff and swap on command ############
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            14         12          2          0          0          3
-/+ buffers/cache:          8          5
Swap:           15          0         15
[sgongali@slc06wvd cronjob]$
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/638387/logout-current-user-from-script That might already be a solution for you.

Comment: I do not recommend abusing of drop_caches 3, maybe 2, and that swapoff. If you need to (ab)use it regularly in a particular VM, maybe it is time to add more RAM.

Comment: Related: [Running a part of shell script as a different user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274650/running-a-part-of-shell-script-as-a-different-user)

Answer (score 0):

Run `which swapoff` and `which swapon`, and use full path in your script. Or update `PATH` env at the begining of the script, and add directory contains those binaries into it.